# Sacar promedio de datos almacenados en matriz | Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual almaceno temperaturas aleatorias en una matriz `12 x 31` (12 meses x 31 dias); mi pregunta es, ¿Cuál sería la manera más óptima para sacar un promedio de las temperaturas de cada mes?.

Esto es lo que he hecho. Gracias de antemano.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] matriz = new int[12][31];
    int i=0,j=0;
    Random random = new Random();
    int min=15,max=38;

    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
        System.out.println("MES # "+(i+1));
        if(i==1){
            for(j=0;j<28;j++){
                matriz[i][j] = min + random.nextInt((max-min)+1);
                System.out.println("Dia "+(j+1)+": "+matriz[i][j]+" grados");
            }
        }
        else if(i==3 || i==5 || i==8 || i==10){
            for(j=0;j<30;j++){
                matriz[i][j] = min + random.nextInt((max-min)+1);
                System.out.println("Dia "+(j+1)+": "+matriz[i][j]+" grados");
            }


        }
        else if(i==0 || i==2 || i==4 || i==6 || i==7 || i==9 || i==11){
            for(j=0;j<31;j++){
                matriz[i][j] = min + random.nextInt((max-min)+1);
                System.out.println("Dia "+(j+1)+": "+matriz[i][j]+" grados");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tal vez la forma mas optima seria usando el stream api, ya lo has probado?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder. Sería posible que me dieras un pequeño ejemplo, es que soy algo nuevo en Java y programación en general... por favor

Comment: De igual manera te recomiendo leer el tutorial de Oracle de [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), es más útil y rápido para estos casos. De hecho, revisa el ejemplo de `class SwitchDemo2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Método 1

Probablemente sea el que te interese más.

**Proceso:**

1. Itera cada mes
2. Suma todos los elementos de ese mes
3. Divide esa suma entre el número de días de ese mes

```java
for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
    double average = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < temperatures[i].length; j++)
        average += temperatures[i][j];

    System.out.printf("Temperatura promedio del mes %d : %f\n", i + 1 , average/temperatures[i].length);
}
```

## Método 2

La manera más sencilla de hacerlo en versiones Java +8 es con [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html), propiamente con [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), el cual tiene directamente el método [IntStream#average](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average()), el cual devuelve un [OptionalDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html) (para evitar errores si el Stream está vacío). Para pasarlo a double, podemos simplemente usar [OptionalDouble#OrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElse(double))

Proceso:

1. Generar el arreglo de los días y meses
2. Por cada mes generamos el `Stream` de datos ([Arrays#stream(int[])](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)))
3. Ese stream lo convertimos a IntStream con `Stream#mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)`
4. Sacamos el promedio
5. Convertimos el OptionalDouble a double

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Generación de datos aleatorios */
        int min = 15, max = 38;
        int monthsInYear = 12;
        Integer[][] temperatures = (Integer[][]) Array.newInstance(Integer[].class, monthsInYear);

        boolean leapYear = LocalDate.now().isLeapYear();

        for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
            int days = LocalDate.now().withMonth(i + 1).getMonth().length(leapYear);

            Array.set(temperatures, i, new Random(System.nanoTime())
                    .ints(days, min, max)
                    .boxed()
                    .toArray(Integer[]::new));
        }

        Arrays.stream(temperatures).forEach(month -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(month)));

        /* Propiamente el problema */
        for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Temperatura promedio del mes %d : %f\n",
                    i + 1,
                    Arrays.stream(temperatures[i])
                            .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                            .average()
                            .orElse(Double.NaN)
            );
        }
    }

}
```

**Nota:** Puedes ignorar la generación de datos aleatorios, pues la pregunta no pide, pero es otra manera en la que lo puedes hacer.

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!! me quedó muy claro :)